# Why can't we upvote or downvote questions in the Triage review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, voting, triage

Why do we not have the option to upvote or downvote a question when reviewing them in the Triage review queue:

[image]

We *do* have the option to upvote or downvote questions/answers in the First Posts review queue.